# Don't uglify certain file when using Microsoft Web Optimization Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-optimization

I am trying to concat lots of .js files into a single one using [Microsoft Web Optimization framework](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/). Everything works, but within those files I have several that are already minified & uglified and there is not need to process them again.

For example I have recaptcha_ajax.js file and it causes following errors when it's appended:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(715,29-36): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break t
(714,293-300): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break t
(678,210-217): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break t
(671,1367-1374): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break t
(665,280-287): run-time error JS1019: Can't have 'break' outside of loop: break t
 */
```

I've tried to take take recaptcha_ajax.js out of bundle and reference it directly, but then other errors popup - so, I need that file within the bundle at certain position.

I just need to be able to say - do not minify & uglify recaptcha_ajax.js - just add it to the bundle.

Is there a way to do this? Here is how I see it:

```
var b = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myjsbundle");

b.IncludeDirectory("~/ScriptsMine/", "*.js", true);

// some command like:
// b.DoNotMinifyOrUglify("~/ScriptsMine/recaptcha_ajax.js");

bundles.Add(b);
```

Comment: are you bundling in the scriptmanager?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Bundles transform each file by using a collection of `IItemTransform` and concatenate result. Then it transform the result by using a collection of `IBundleTransform`.

The default script bundle minifies the complete bundle content by using `JsMinify` (which implements `IBundleTransform`).

So to prevent some file from minifying, you have to create your own `IBundleBuilder` which minifies the bundle file by file by using an `IItemTransform`.

```
public class CustomScriptBundle : Bundle
{
    public CustomScriptBundle(string virtualPath)
        : this(virtualPath, null)
    {
    }

    public CustomScriptBundle(string virtualPath, string cdnPath)
        : base(virtualPath, cdnPath, null)
    {
        this.ConcatenationToken = ";" + Environment.NewLine;
        this.Builder = new CustomBundleBuilder();
    }
}


public class CustomBundleBuilder : IBundleBuilder
{
    internal static string ConvertToAppRelativePath(string appPath, string fullName)
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appPath) || !fullName.StartsWith(appPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? fullName : fullName.Replace(appPath, "~/")).Replace('\\', '/');
    }

    public string BuildBundleContent(Bundle bundle, BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        if (files == null)
            return string.Empty;
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        if (bundle == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bundle");

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (BundleFile bundleFile in files)
        {
            bundleFile.Transforms.Add(new CustomJsMinify());
            stringBuilder.Append(bundleFile.ApplyTransforms());
            stringBuilder.Append(bundle.ConcatenationToken);
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}

public class CustomJsMinify : IItemTransform
{
    public string Process(string includedVirtualPath, string input)
    {
        if (includedVirtualPath.EndsWith("min.js", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return input;
        }

        Minifier minifier = new Minifier();
        var codeSettings = new CodeSettings();
        codeSettings.EvalTreatment = EvalTreatment.MakeImmediateSafe;
        codeSettings.PreserveImportantComments = false;

        string str = minifier.MinifyJavaScript(input, codeSettings);

        if (minifier.ErrorList.Count > 0)
            return "/* " + string.Concat(minifier.Errors) + " */";

        return str;
    }
}
```

Then use the `CustomScriptBundle` instead of `ScriptBundle`

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new CustomScriptBundle("~/bundles/Sample").Include(
                "~/Scripts/a.js",
                "~/Scripts/b.js",
                "~/Scripts/c.js"));
}
```

If you provide a `min.js` file it will be used instead of minifying it.

Comment: This doesn't handle the case when the bundle includes the min and non-min versions of a library, right? It should use <compilation debug> in the config file to decide which one to use. This processing could be added before the foreach in the BuildBundleContent method.

Comment: This code was not fully tested, so you may do some changes to make it work as you want

Answer (score 3):

The optimization framework takes filenames into account.

Try to rename your *.js file to recaptcha_ajax.min.js. If I'm correct, then it should skip the uglify/minify process.

Reference data : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification
(scroll down a bit to find this quote:)

> The preceding code creates a new JavaScript bundle named
>   ~/bundles/jquery that includes all the appropriate (that is debug or
>   minified but not .vsdoc) files in the Scripts folder that match the
>   wild card string "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js". For ASP.NET MVC 4,
>   this means with a  debug configuration, the file jquery-1.7.1.js will
>   be added to the bundle. In a release configuration, 
>   jquery-1.7.1.min.js will be added. The bundling framework follows
>   several common conventions such as:
>
> - Selecting “.min” file for release when “FileX.min.js” and “FileX.js”    exist.
> - Selecting the non “.min” version for debug.
> - Ignoring “-vsdoc” files    (such as jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js), which are    used only by IntelliSense.

Comment: It would be awesome if it worked like this. But, it seems it doesn't - I've created separate hello.js and hello.min.js to test and it minifies regardless of .min. in name. Maybe I'm missing some setting?

Comment: Have you tried to run it in release mode? It should work this way :s

Comment: I think it's just bad engineering - web optimization framework has so many switches that it seems directly changing bundle building process is the  only way to control it. Example: regardless of Debug/Release mode, BundleTable.EnableOptimizations takes precedence (which is a GOOD thing). If BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false, script.js file will be picked. For true, script.min.js. BUT - BOTH files will be minified regardless of the file name. I would love if they open-sourced code so we could help them a bit with design decisions (i.e. didn't minify for .min.js in filename).

Answer (score 1):

if you are bundling .js files in the ScriptManager you will notice that scripts are loaded in the `<form>`, not the `<head>` so pulling it out of the bundle will load that file before the others, which is not good if it's dependent other things in the bundle

Here is an example of a library that needs to be added to the bundle in a specific order.
This is added to App_Start/BundleConfig.vb

```
'############################################################
' This is a ScriptManager Resource Definition 
' for use in a ScriptManager mapping
'############################################################
    Dim ResourceDef as ScriptResourceDefinition = New ScriptResourceDefinition()
    Dim ResourceName as  String = "ColorBox"

    'add the Resource Definition details
    ResourceDef.Path = "~/Scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"
    ResourceDef.DebugPath = "~/Scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"

    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(ResourceName, ResourceDef)
'############################################################
```

Note the use of `ResourceDef.Path` and `ResourceDef.DebugPath`. 
Which file gets included will depend on you making a Debug or Release publish

- Debug: no "uglification"
- Release: Total "uglification"

This is my ScriptManager bundle, note the placement of ColorBox, position means a lot:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" >
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="ColorBox" />          
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Infragistics" /> 
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```