# How to turn off minification on selected bundles?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

It may sound ridiculous because minification is one of main reasons of bundling, and there's always an option to use plain old `<script src='...'/>` instead of bundles mechanism, but is there any way to turn off minification on a particular bundle in ASP.NET MVC?

I know we could turn on `debug="true"` in web.config or set `EnableOptimizations` flag to false, but all of this turns off minification at global level. Is there any way to do it on a single bundle scope?

Comment: I think you can get inspiration from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23022586/dont-uglify-certain-file-when-using-microsoft-web-optimization-framework/23142111#23142111

Answer (score -1):

You can add this to your bundle config:

```
#if DEBUG
        foreach (var bundle in BundleTable.Bundles)
            {
                if (bundle.Path = "~/yourbundle")
                {
                    bundle.Transforms.Clear();
                }
            }
#endif
```